# (RuntimeError: Form data has been processed already) What does it mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, aiohttp

I was working on a discord bot that needed to send a file. The only change I can think of from previous file-sending situations that worked for me was that the encoding of the file was ISO-8859-1 instead of utf-8. I made the TextIO object with `with open(filepath,'r',encoding='ISO-8859-1') as mp3`, then under that, I used `await channel.send(file=discord.File(mp3))`(on later testing, even if I move the discord.File call to another line, the error is in the send method). The send line of code thew a huge chain of errors, ending with `RuntimeError: Form data has been processed already`. What does this error mean in my context, and what do I do to fix it? Thanks in advance!

For reference, here's the full exception chain:

````
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/nathanwolf/Documents/coding/PycharmProjects/lyrics bot/main.py", line 75, in on_message
    await message.channel.send(file=discord.File(mp3))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 915, in send
    data = await state.http.send_files(channel.id, files=[file], allowed_mentions=allowed_mentions,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 185, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 492, in _request
    req = self._request_class(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 313, in __init__
    self.update_body_from_data(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 507, in update_body_from_data
    body = body()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/formdata.py", line 168, in __call__
    return self._gen_form_data()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/formdata.py", line 132, in _gen_form_data
    raise RuntimeError("Form data has been processed already")
RuntimeError: Form data has been processed already```
````

Comment: Are you using an older or modified version of discord.py? Because I couldn't find anything regarding this

Comment: it wasn't a discord error, it had to do with the http request process it appears

Comment: @FlexGames your suggestion partially worked: I updated discord.py and now it doesn't throw the old error, it throws a can't send empty message error. Thanks for the help, but given that I specified the content parameter in the send call, as well as including a file, why might it be throwing the empty message error?

Comment: Can you maybe edit your question with the new code and so I can see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, but it isn't entirely clear how I did it. Updating discord.py worked, but then the error came back once I tried to change the encoding on the mp3 file to utf-8 so discord could read it. I got around it by not giving a `TextIO` object to the `discord.File()` method and instead gave it the name of the file. Somehow that worked.